# macOS finder big bars between columns views

Tags: mac, finder

This is really weird, sometimes these bars are not there and sometimes they are. They also appear in another program like iTerm2. Does anyone know what these are? And how I can disable them...

[image: iTerm2 window]
[image: Finder window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are **Scroll Bars**.

**When** they appear is dependant on your setting in System Prefs > General...

[image]